# How to unload unsued COM objects/libraries after a complete restart?

Tags: c#, windows, com

Here is the thing. I'm connecting via COM to some devices at KNX/EIB. But sometimes - and I want to be ready for worst-case anyways - my application crashes leaving all objects and libraries exposed somewhere, somehow. I noticed when I restart the app I have trouble to get a connection again. I get an error for a connection procedure that is actually working well normally. Sometimes this connect procedure is working sometimes it is not, randomly. That is bad! After some time (several minutes) it seems to work again after a series of complete fails. But I think I see a pattern now. It doesn't work after a crash with no clean disconnect. My guess is there are objects that hold a connection to the device that us why I can't get a new connection. This is why I ask this question.

---

**Question:**

- How do I unload those unused objects to kill undead connections?
- How do I make Windows to check for unused libraries to be unloaded?

I just want to tell Windows, "I messed up badly and I need to continue my work. Please clean up my mess for me, so I can start fresh! Do I deserve a 2nd chance?"

**Edit:**
The scenario is the app has crashed and closed. I have no references to anything anymore. No finally clause or anything. The app can only be started again. What can I do to clean up the mess that has been made before, programmatically?

**Edit 2:**
Hans gave me the hint of killing the responsible server. So for now I solve that with calling taskkill on startup (at least as long I'm in dev). And it works!

```
C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /F /IM Falcon.exe
```

Comment: you probably need to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject (in a finally block or exception handler or something)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield My disconnect procedures are full of that. But like I said, I want to prepare for the worst case. The app crashed and as user all I can do is to restart it.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is on the other end of the connection, either an out of process object or a fault intolerant service. I think the best you can do here is build your app to recognize this condition and deal with it on startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the failure mode of an out-of-process COM server.  If the client program crashes to the desktop without releasing the interface pointers then the server is completely unaware that the client isn't around anymore.  And tends to get balky when you try to reconnect, many servers just permit one client.

By far the most common way that programmers induce this failure mode is by using a debugger.  They'll click the Red Button or use the Stop Debugging command.  Bam, no cleanup of course.

COM garbage-collects unused servers automatically.  But that isn't particularly fast, takes an easy 10 minutes before it decides it needs to step in.  And doesn't always work for every server, Office programs notoriously don't get cleaned-up for example.

Not much you can do about this when your app keels over in regular usage.  Otherwise the kind of problem that killed middle-ware.  Still, having such a mishap in a C# program is pretty unusual, the CLR releases interface pointers at program termination even when the app crashed with an exception.  You'd have to have the very nasty kind of mishaps to bypass this, critical exceptions like ExecutionEngineException or the one this site is named after.

Don't focus too much on the Stop Debugging induced failures, it is normal and using Task Manager to kill the server is expected and required.  Otherwise just be sure to get the nasty bugs out of your code and you won't have a problem.  If you need more help then be sure to contact the owner of the server, be sure to have a small repro project available that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Actually I've been using taskkill to get rid of Office servers. Maybe it's not a bad idea. All I have to do is to find the server and get rid of it at startup? I'll see if that works. It helped me with Excel back then. I was so annoyed when my prog didn't work, when I stopped my Debug app with two key hits (so used to and convenient).

Comment: Taskkill or Task Manager, it doesn't matter.  You tend to have better odds at hitting the right one with the GUI.

Comment: And "taskkill" works. Your tip to use Task Manager helped me to remember I did that with "EXCEL.EXE".